# Asp Web Api authorization with existing custom users table

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have an existing desktop.NET (framework 3.5) application. There exists a `custom table` for users (name,password...). I want to put the db online and create a Web Api

Is it possible to secure the Api using existing users table?
I want a simple checking if user and password exists in current db.
Db will be accessed from desktop app,so structure must remain the same

I don't have experience with ASP MVC so I need a clue in how to secure Api controller in this case

thanks.

Comment: Yah! You can do that.

Comment: any clue on this?

Comment: You need to call your Api method from desktop app, no matter where ever your Api and DB hosted. But yes, to call the Api you need to modify your desktop app source code. I hope you have the source code for your desktop app. After changes, you can re-install your app in your PC.

Comment: I have the source code.desktop application works fine with Ado.NET. There is no need to change it.I want to create a mobile application with Angular 2 that access couple data from database that why I need Web Api.I need couple details how to secure Api Controller in situation described

Comment: seems a custom authorize attribute restrict the api.but I don't know where to search/study in order to use my users table
 and not send password to api as plain text.  thanks